# Loop through multiple of same blocks of markup in JS and perform same function without interference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, underscore.js

I am looking to to fade in / out text labels, where only one label shows at a time in a given block. The markup is like this:

```
 <div class="subtitles">
   <h3 class="subtitle" data-order="0">
     label 1
   </h3>
   <h3 class="subtitle" data-order="1">
     label 2
   </h3>
   <h3 class="subtitle" data-order="3">
     label 3
   </h3>
 </div>

 [repeat block nth number of times]
```

I can loop through one set fine with this javascript:

```
 var divs = $('.subtitles').find('h3.subtitle');
  divs.hide();
      i = 0;

  //    fade h3s in / out
  (function cycle() {
    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut(400, cycle);

    i = ++i % 3;
  })();
```

But more than one block on the page and things get tangled. How can I loop over multiple blocks and apply the same behaviour?

Comment: Do you require the separate blocks to have their animations completely synchronised?  (a corollary of this is that they each have the same number of child nodes)

Comment: no, they can begin at different intervals if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.each()`

Code:
`$('.subtitles').each(function() {$(this).find('h3.subtitle');$(this).hide()});`

Edit: According to question OP, the `i` variable is getting variabletangled, and the reason is due to javascript Hoisting. Please read this link, to understand what is happening to the

Comment: thanks - I did this, however `i` gets tangled and it is not applied consistently accross each block

Comment: most likely because you didn't declare `var i` making it global by mistake

Comment: (it's not a "hoisting" problem either.  It's a plain case of global vs local, whereas hoisting relates to variables declared anywhere in a function behind treated as if they had been declared at the top of the function)

Answer (score 1):

You need to *encapsulate* the desired behaviour in a function, so that each set of cycling elements gets its own offset.

```
function cycle($els) {
    var i = 0;
    $els.hide();
    (function loop() {
        $els.eq(i++).fadeIn(400)
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut(400, loop);
        i %= $els.length;
    })();
}
```

and then you can use `.each` to start each group of subtitles cycling around independently:

```
$('.subtitles').each(function() {
    cycle($(this).find('h3.subtitle'));
});
```

Comment: upvoting as more elegant than what I have

Comment: @Rockafella it's a good habit to break code into these smaller functional units when they're non-trivial.   Whilst you _could_ inline the `cycle` function within the `.each` callback, having it in a separate generic function allows for _reuse_.